# seperate row made of numbers to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following data in pandas from a .CSV file:

```
ABC
123
DEF       
456  
GHI   
789
```

But I want to separate the row made of numbers to a new column like:

```
ABC   123  
DEF   456 
GHI   789
```

Any idea how I can do this in pandas?
thank you.

Comment: Check out that link from @RJAdriaansen. There are some good answers using Pandas, and I also added one using just Python's standard CSV reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(df['YOUR_COLUMN'].values.reshape(-1, 2), columns=['Letters', 'Numbers'])
```

Comment: thank you this is great! But ive got the problem that in my list ther are linse like:    A   1   B   2  C   D   3  E..... and then the then its wrong. any idea? thx :)

Comment: Will you please add the output of `print(df.to_dict())` to the question? It would help me a lot.

Comment: `{'Letters': {0: '00605558', 1: '00605613', 2: 'Smm Headphone', 3: 'Apple iPhone Lightning Doc* Black', 4: 'Apple EarPods wilh Lighining Con', 5: 'Huawel GigaCube LTE CPE Fenstera', 6: 'Google Home', 7: 'Belkin BOOSTUP Wireless Charger', 8: 'Google Hame Mlni', 9: 'Huawei P20 Pro Sllicon Case Blue', 10: 'Apple 29WV USB \x80 Pewer Adapter', 11: 'Huawei Matezo Lile TPU case tran;', 12: 'Huawel', 13: '00608094', 14: 'Generation)', 15: 'Apple Waich Nike Sport Band schw;', 16: 'Apple AlrPeds wlth Wirel Chargi;', 17: 'Apple AirPods wilh Charging Case',`              it the article number and the name

Comment: it from a scannet papper to a csv file. but the Optical Character Recognition got sometimes some problem of formatting